# Use Linked Server in Execute SQL Task within SSIS Package

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, ssis

I have a package that has a main sql execute task.  Within that task I need to call two databases (A,B) each on a different server.  There is a linked server(B) within the main server(A) I am using.  I can't split them out however due to they join on each other many times on many different tables in separate scripts.  The main script is a large amount of unions pulling data in to report off of in a later task.

I have my linked server call in my sql script but it says it can't connect.  Is there a way I can connect to this linked server as I do when I run the sql script from sql server?  Or is there a way to make a connection within the SSIS package and refer to it somehow within a task or in the script?

Comment: Consider adding the error code(s) you are receiving.

Comment: Error I'm seeing is: [Execute SQL Task] Error: Executing the query "QUERY DETAILS" failed with the following error: "Could not find server 'LINKED SERVER' in sys.servers. 
Verify that the correct server name was specified. If necessary, execute the stored procedure sp_addlinkedserver to add the server to sys.servers.". 
Possible failure reasons: Problems with the query, "ResultSet" property not set correctly, parameters not set correctly, or connection not established correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Proxy Account has setup proper Login credential/user with permission to execute your task at main server(A) and able to access linked server(B).

Use Log Viewer at SSMS to see the error message.

See example at following URL:-

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/

Comment: I checked the permissions and they seem to be set to access the linked server as expected.  I will dig more into your document you sent however and get back with what I find.